# How can I use the branded Google, Facebook, etc. login buttons with OAuth in my ASP .Net Core (MVC) application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth, google-signin

The ASP .Net Core MVC project template has some functionality built in to support Individual User Accounts, including OAuth for Google, Facebook, and Twitter. **The standard buttons are just plain, lame buttons however, and I would much rather use the branded buttons from Facebook, Google, Twitter, et al.**

I understand that there are basically two apporaches to OAuth: Front-end authentication, and back-channel authentication, where the latter involves the server making a server-provider (provider being Facebook, Google, or whomever) call, passing the application's key and requested permissions, with a callback to the server from the provider when authentication is complete, whereas the former is a direct call from the front-end (e.g. Javascript in the browser) to the provider, utilizing controls that are built from CSS and Javascript provided by the individual providers.

What I would like to do is something of a hybrid approach-- I would like to use those nice, branded buttons with their imagery (i.e., the Facebook button shows the users picture if they're logged in; Google's might as well), but I want to pass the authentication information back to my back-end (so I can manage the user's permissions to do stuff on my website.) Is this possible? If so, what mechanism would I use to do it, and it it possible to integrate that approach with all the stuff that's already built into the MVC template and the framework?

One interesting thing that I read in the official docs from facebook on the use of their control suggested that you should protect your application's key, to prevent someone else from stealing it and misusing it, presumably impersonating you or your site for nefarious purposes. Obviously, that would be one huge advantage to using back-channel authentication, because nowhere in that stream, from the user's perspective, is your application key ever seen; when using the javascript approach documented by the provider's branded buttons, you end up having to store your application key right there in plain text in the javascript, and there doesn't seem to be a way around that, which seems odd, given that they tell you that is precisely what you DON'T want to be doing.

So, to summarize:

1. If I use the javascript approach to get the branded buttons, how do I protect my application key from being scraped and misused by a third party?
2. How can I get the authentication information that comes back from Facebook or other providers from the javascript (branded) controls, and then feed that information to my backend? Is it possible to wire that into the existing framework stuff that handles authentication and authorization, or will I then have to home-brew everything?

Those login buttons from the various providers seem simple enough, but in reality they appear to be a lot more than just image buttons-- There seems to be a lot of magic going on in the javascript and CSS, but it seems like this should be possible. Almost every site that I visit that has "Login with Google" buttons and the like is using the nice, pretty branded buttons, and I'm sure the sites are not written entirely in Javascript. Thanks for any help!

---

Thanks for the early replies! A quick update that I have gotten the Google Sign-In button to work, and I can read a response back from Google and can thus see that sign-in attempt was successful. **Now what I'm looking to do is to somehow pass that information back to my server-side application so I can sign the user in to my website.** Here is the Javascript that have now. The function *initGoogleButton*, if present, is apparently called by Google's code to allow me to customize the button and set various parameters.

```
    <script>
        function onSuccess(googleUser) {

            id = googleUser.getId();
            scopes = googleUser.getGrantedScopes();
            alert("Id: " + id + ", Scopes: " + scopes);

            profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            id = profile.getId();
            name = profile.getName();
            givenName = profile.getGivenName();
            familyName = profile.getFamilyName();
            email = profile.getEmail();
            image = profile.getImageUrl();

            alert("Id: " + id + ", name: " + name + ", Given: " + givenna + " family: " + familyName + ", email: " + email + ", image: " + getImageUrl);

            document.getElementById('externalLoginForm').Submit();
            console.log('Logged in as: ' + googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName());
            alert("Success!");
        }

        function onFailure() {
            alert("Failure!");
        }

        function renderGoogleButton() {
            gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
                scope: 'profile email',
                width: 250,
                height: 40,
                longtitle: true,
                theme: 'dark',
                onsuccess: onSuccess,
                onfailure: onFailure,
            });
        }

        function onGoogleInit(authObj) {
            alert("Signed in == " + authObj.isSignedIn.get());
            alert("onGoogleInit");

            if (authObj.isSignedIn.get()) {
                //authObj.signOut();
            }

            renderGoogleButton();
        }

        function onGoogleInitError(authError) {
            alert("Auth Error!");
            alert(authError.error);
        }

        function initGoogleButton() {
            alert("Init");
            gapi.load('auth2', function () {
                promise = gapi.auth2.init({
                    client_id: '12345678987654321-blahblahblahMyAppId12345.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                    //scope: "email profile",
                    //fetch_basic_profile: true,
                    //redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:44359/Account/Callback',
                }).then(onGoogleInit, onGoogleInitError);
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=initGoogleButton" async defer></script>
```

So you'll note the commented out code there where I was trying to provide a callback for Google to send the authentication message back to my controller. That never worked. My Alert() calls though were properly showing me the Id and scopes that Google gave back.

When doing the built-in sign-in functionality in the MVC template, you have a button on a form that invokes a backend call in your controller that does a few async calls to sign you in with the authenticated Google account credentials and, if you don't have an account on the website, invites you to register. Those calls are using a lot of framework stuff for authentication and I'd like to leverage it.

```
        using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "externalLoginForm" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div id="socialLoginList">
                <p>
                    @* Google login button *@
                    <div class="g-signin2" data-height="40" data-width="250" data-theme="dark" data-redirecturi="https://localhost:44359/signin-google"></div><br />
                    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
                    @* Facebook login button *@
                    <div class="fb-login-button" data-width="250" data-size="large" data-button-type="login_with" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true"></div><br />
                    @* Configured social media logins *@
                    @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders)
                    {
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" title="Log in using your @p.Caption account">@p.AuthenticationType</button>
                    }
                </p>
            </div>
        }
```

Then, in the external login action in the controller...

```
        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
        {
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        }
```

This, in turn causes an ExecuteResult on the ChallengeResult, which is what takes you to the Google page, which is fed the Account/ExternalLoginCallback as its callback point.

It is the callback that then does all the stuff to either sign you in to the website, or invite you to register if you don't have a local account. A lot of this is using stuff from the OWinContext or other things I don't seem to have access to. Obviously I could home-brew my own solution, but I'd prefer if there was a nice, clean way to just wire into the rest of this stuff that's already done. After all, all I wanted are those nice, pretty branded buttons. :) I'm totally fine with the way that the framework is doing the rest of this.

Comment: The application key should will never be in the Javascript code. Where did you read that?

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing the app id (exposing that in client-side code is not really a problem; rather it is a necessity for the whole thing to work in the first place), and the app secret - which of course should never be exposed in client-side code, and isn’t needed there when using the provided login button solutions. The app secret (that’s what Facebook calls it, other providers terminology might differ slightly) is a secret shared between you and the provider, and can be used to prove that server-side requests are coming from a genuine source.

Comment: _“but in reality they appear to be a lot more than just image buttons”_ - yes, they are. First of all, they reside in an iframe, to prevent that you have any direct scripting access to them. Communication between the button and your page usually happens via `postMessage`. The advantage these client-side solutions have, is that they can “recognize” an already authenticated user on their next visit to your page - because the client has the cookies for the provider domain stored and can send them there to check the status, any server-side solution obviously doesn’t have that kind of access.

Comment: @WizKid thanks, I think I did misread that in the FB docs, or they didn't articulate it very clearly. I do have both an App Id and App Secret, and no I did not ever share the app secret in the client-side code, although I thought I had read somewhere in the docs that you really shouldn't expose your app Id either, but then it seems that it would be difficult do this without it. I guess that is one advantage of the approach with the lame system buttons in MVC template-- All the communication with the provider is done on the back channel so you don't expose anything.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks. With regard to the App Id and the App Secret, given that the app secret ensures the provider that your backend application is really you when it requests permissions for a user, would you say that makes a backend implementation inherently more secure than a full front-end implementation? I mean, if a front end application can also request permissions from the provider, but can do so with only your App Id, and anyone can get that and thus pretend to be your app, that does seem risk. Did I miss something?

Comment: Speaking mainly about Facebook here (less experience with Google’s stuff) - an app id alone doesn’t get you far. FB API requests always require an access token these days, and the client-side login implementation is limited to the domains configured in your app settings in a secure-enough way - no one will be able to just put your app id into their own code, and then have users login to your app from _their_ website.

Comment: @CBroe, I did get the Google Sign-in button working on my test site, and I was able to get the values back from Google for the signed-in user. Please see my above edit to the question... what I'm wanting to know now is, how can I (or is it even possible) to wire that response from Google into the existing framework code that handles user authentication?

Comment: Couldn’t tell you, I don’t know that framework. The only thing you should send from the client to the server, is an access token (don’t send user ids or anything like that determined on the client side, that’s easily fakeable), and then use that to make server-side API requests from there, to get any further user details. The framework probably checks at some point, whether a valid user token is available in the session. If it triggers any automatic redirects or makes specific outputs into the page based on not finding one, you’ll have to figure out how to modify its behavior in those places.